# Very specific output format Python

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, tabular

I am trying to figure out how to print in the terminal specifically as follows:

[image: Table]

and then write it to a .txt file.

**My Attempt:**

I have been using "tabulate" for a while, so my natural go to attempt was to use the library. Here is my code:

```
    from tabulate import tabulate
    import numpy as np

    lista  = np.zeros(4)
    print(tabulate([lista, lista], headers=['n', r'$\phi_{n}$', 'a_{n}', 'e_{n}'], 
    numalign="center"))

    with open('table.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(tabulate([lista, lista], headers=['n', r'$\phi_{n}$', 'a_{n}', 'e_{n}'], numalign="center"))
```

The above code generates the following result:

[image: Resulting image]

Which is nice, but not what i want. I tried to delete the 'headers' parameter, but it still gives me a table containing a header like structure. Furthermore, it does not contain the '&' character I need nor the '\' thing. I suspect i might need to do it manually somehow.

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: The desired output looks like a latex table without `\begin{tabular}`, `\hline`, `\end{tabular}`, etc. If that's the case, `print(tabulate([lista, lista], tablefmt="latex"))` should bring you (somewhat) close.

Comment: Yes! I was thinking of maybe reading the .txt file and deleting what does not matter structure wise, but I dont know how to do it also.

Comment: Try something like: `print('\n'.join(line for line in tabulate([lista, lista], tablefmt="latex").split('\n') if '&' in line))`.

Comment: It worked!!! However, can you please explain how this piece of code works? I just dont see how the code managed to delete the header like structure ):

Comment: That's just a quick and dirty hack. The `if '&' in line` piece just results in keeping the rows that have a `&`. As the `\begin{tabular}`, `\hline`, `\end{tabular}`, etc. rows don't include a latex column separator, i.e., `&`, they are filtered out.

Comment: Curiosity: Do you know how to write equations and symbols in the header? I tried using r'$\phi_{n}$', but it does not work.